# Balls thrown into baskets randomly

Tags: probability

4 balls are thrown randomly into two baskets (Basket A, Basket B), what is the probability that 2 or more balls will be in Basket A,
I'm not sure im correct but

$\Omega = 5$.
because there are 5 outcomes {4,0} , {3,1} , {2,2} , {1,3} , {0,4}
three of them are good.
so $\frac35$ is the answer?

I forgot to mention if Basket A is full, it is removed so all the rest of the balls will be in Basket B. ( Basket A can contain maximum of 2 balls )

Comment: If basket $A$ can contain a maximum of $2$ balls, it makes no sense to ask for the probability that it contains "$2$ or more balls".

Comment: You are correct, but I have trouble phrasing it so you will understand exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Note:  the answer below was posted prior to a significant edit of the question, but it is still valid.  Specifically, what follows calculates the probability that at least two of the tosses are directed at $A$.  If, as the edit suggests, all balls in excess of $2$ are redirected to $B$ that does not alter the calculation in any way.

The phrasing is (somewhat) ambiguous.  Your calculation would be correct if you imagine that "randomly" means that you choose with uniform probability amongst the $5$ options...but that's an unusual interpretation of the language.  When you say the balls "are thrown randomly" I take that to mean that each ball is thrown separately and has an equal probability of winding up in either basket.

Assuming that:  Each ball has an independent probability of $\frac 12$ of winding up in Basket $A$.  If $p_n$ denotes the probability that exactly $n$ balls end in basket $A$ then the answer you want is $p_2+p_3+p_4$.  This is just a standard binomial distribution (like coin tosses) so $p_n=\binom 4n \times \frac 1{16}$ Combining, we see that the answer you want is $$\frac 1{16}\times \left(6+4+1\right)=.6875$$

Comment: You are correct, each ball thrown separately, and has an equal probability. I can't understand why my answer doesn't apply to that statement

Comment: This answers the originally posted question, which has since been changed completely.

Comment: @joriki  Does the edit change the answer?  $.687$ is the probability that the sequence of throws will contain two or more $A's$.  That coincides with the probability that $A$ winds up with two balls in it, or have I not woken up yet?

Comment: @Kikapi  the five states you describe are not of equal probability.

Comment: @lulu: No, it's me who hasn't woken up yet -- in fact coincidentally I was just saying exactly that to a friend an hour ago to explain all the typos I made :-) You're quite right.

Answer (score 0):

**I also answered the original question** where there was no restriction on how many balls fit in A. The goal of my answer would be to explain the numbers in lulu:s answer a bit better. One way I usually try to explain this is by using the binomial theorem.

$$(a+b)^4 = 1a^4 + 4a^3b + 6a^2b^2 + 4ab^3 + 1b^4$$

Each new  "selects" if we hit basket $A$ (a) or $B$ (b). Then the exponents tell us how many of each basket we hit and the coefficient for how many of the configurations that occurs. For example to hit basket $a$ three times, this can be done in 4 configurations:
$$\begin{array}{ll}aaab & : \text{a 3 times in a row, then $b$} \\ aaba & : \text{a 2 times in a row, then $b$, and then $a$ again}\\abaa &  : \text{a once, then $b$, and then $a$ two times in a row}\\ baaa & \text{: b once, and then a 3 times in a row}\end{array}$$
And $4$ is also the number before $a^3b$.

I hope this helps make sense of lulu:s answer that we should add up all of the coefficients with a exponent $\geq 2$.